# Values pulled from firestore on page load before the actual search happens

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering why the below code is pulling in values from Firestore on page load even without me punching in any searchterm. If I start punching in a matching search value I don't see any results as well. Its working the opposite way now. I want it to pull values from the Firestore only when the user puts in a search term. Please advise!

```
class _ConversationsState extends State<Conversations> {
  String _searchTerm ='';
  Future<void> _signOut() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e); // TODO: show dialog with error
    }
  }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Search'),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _searchTerm = value.trim();
                });
              },
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
            stream: (_searchTerm != "") ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .where('email', arrayContains: _searchTerm )
                .snapshots() : FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots(),
                builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
              }
              final results = snapshot.data.docs;
                  print(results.length);
              return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: results.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Text(
                  results[index].data()['email'],
                  //chatDocs[index].data()['email'] == user.uid,
                ),
              );
            })
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reverse your ternary operator here

`FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('users') .where('email', arrayContains: _searchTerm ) .snapshots() : FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots(),` on

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots() :   FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('users') .where('email', arrayContains: _searchTerm ) .snapshots()`

Comment: Thanks Simon. You solved what I asked here. But I am wondering now why is it also pulling in all values when I search for a specific value.

Comment: I am not near my laptop so its a bit hard from phone, but what i would do here is validate `_searchTerm` before it will query database - regex or at least has 5 chars

Comment: And validation on string must be done with .isEmpty statement on controller(if i remember correct) of the field and not with !='' because two objects are not same instance and therefore it might never resolve to false.

Comment: StreamBuilder(stream: (_searchTerm.length >= 3)) Simon, as of now I am doing the check this way, still after 5 chars it pulls in all values from Firestore